Does anybody know with which data type should I send info to a VT08F GPS in order to get an answer back from it?
I'm in the process of implementing a socket to communicate with a VT-08F GPS, which has a similar protocol to GT-06 Concox GPS.
According to the protocol, whenever you get a login packet (like "78 78 11 01 03 55 46 85 91 24 52 79 28 01 21 2a 00 01 04 5f 0d 0a"), you're supposed to respond with:
7878 + message length (which is 05) + 01 (login protocol) + 0001 (sequence number found within the packet) + d9dc (the CRC ITU calculation of the message length + login + sequence number characters, in this case it's d9dc) + 0d0a (stop bits)
So far I've managed to get the values according to what they show in the protocol and I've managed to get the GPS to send me info through a socket, but the problem is that whenever I try to send the answer back to the GPS, it gets the answer but it doesn't send locations back.
$responseArray = str_split(strtoupper("787805$protocol$sequenceId$crc" . "0d0a"), 2);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($responseArray); $i++) {
    $response .= chr(hexdec(trim($responseArray[$i])));
}
if ($socket) {
    fwrite($socket, $response);
}

The protocol doesn't mention whether I should send strings, numeric values, hex values, or ASCII values to the GPS. I've already tried sending the response as a raw string, but still no answer.
The CRC values are correct, and the rest of the values are just like in the protocol. Has anybody worked with this GPS reference before? If so, in which format have you sent it the info to get it to start reporting GPS locations?
